# Trying to call functions based on IRC user input

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python, but not new to programming. Basically, I'm trying to call certain functions/procedures to simulate keyboard/mouse based on user input from an IRC channel.

I am running an IRC bot on twitch like a twitch plays sort of thing. I know how to simulate keyboard and mouse input, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this efficiently.

I have a class for the bot and it starts like:

```
class bot:
def __init__(self):
    ...
    login stuff
    ...
    self.options = {'!test': self.command_test,
    'q': self.quickSave,
    'f': self.forward,
    'ff': self.forward2,
    'fff': self.forward3
    }
    ...
```

and then the functions are called while the bot parses IRC chat input like so:

```
def parse_message(self, msg):
    if len(msg) >= 1:
        msg = msg.split(' ')
        if msg[0] in self.options:
            self.options[msg[0]]()
```

I have a load of functions that are basically the same only repeated. (forward, forward2, forward3, left, left2, left3, etc). It really makes no sense to repeat the same function over and over. I cannot figure out how to efficiently call these functions like forward(1), forward(2), forward(3), etc.

I would like my code to look like this:

```
def forward(self, num):
    for x in range(1, num):
        #Simulate walking forward
```

I just cant figure out how to add arguments to forward() using simple text input. This is hard for me to explain, just imagine a hundred people voting to move/aim in a video game in an IRC channel.

Again, I'm not asking for help emulating mouse/keyboard input. I just need advice about how to use text to call functions.

*if it help you understand, i'm attempting to croudplay fallout 4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, each command is actually one symbol, and repeating a symbol `n` times means calling the associated function the same amount of times, right?

Assuming `command` is a string of symbols without spaces, it could be done like that:

```
command = #get command

for char in command:
    your_dict[char]()
```

BTW, it's not really needed to check whether the dictionary contains the specified command. Just wrap the calling into a `try/except` block:

```
try
   your_dict[char]()
except KeyError:
    # this is OK, tell the user that it's an error
except:
    # this means that some of the functions has raised an error
```

Comment: Well, the commands aren't always restricted to one character. for example, there's quicksave (qs), quickload (ql), turn 45 degrees, 90 degrees. Only some commands can be iterated like that; however, this answer will help for a lot of movement commands thank you.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. At least in the testing stage: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AyPd0xLT)

Comment: @WillPile, that's great news, I'm happy it worked! To deal with the commands that are more than one char in length, you could implement some simple parsing: for example, if the current character is `q`, try to retrieve the next char. If it's `s` or `l` extract both and use as a key, extract only the current char otherwise.